# Blazor Webassembly - calling external API

Tags: httpclient, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have been trying to call a separate asp.net core web api from with in a Blazor client side web assembly.   I used the templates web API template with this controller.  I have CORS set up in the startup.cs.  I am using the standard HTTP client with in the Blazor Client.  Running locally I can set a break point on the API code and see it get hit.  But the client is throwing an exception: **Type Error**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

David

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}

Startup.cs
     services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                  builder =>
                                  {
                                      builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                                          "http://www.contoso.com")
                                                          .AllowAnyOrigin()
                                                          .AllowAnyMethod()
                                                          .AllowAnyHeader();
                                  });
            });

Blazor Client
var response = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("WeatherForecast");
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same kind of error and upon using the developer tool console , looks like the mixed content is not allowed (both https and http).Mixed Content: The page at 'https://' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.  Check whether this is the case with your pages too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your url must be complete for example https://www.xxxxxx.com.... or http://www.xxxxxx.com....
2. For  published API with paid ssl certificate to get data from API on client side

Example:

```
private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

public TblMenuSER(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
}

public async  Task<IEnumerable<TblMenus>>Getoutput()
{
    return await this.httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<TblMenus[]>("https://xxxxx.com/BLZ/api/GETData/x,x,x,x");
}
```